# How to upgrade VMOS or Virtual Android to Android 12?

Tags: updates, android-12, virtualization

Both VMOS and Virtual Android was updated recently to support Android 12 (instead of Android 7 as both were limited to before). However, I don't understand how to update them. I have found several YouTube-clips, e.g.,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsr-eqEWOns

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiZmKx3v5f4&t=34s

claiming to described the process but they are just confusing. Besides, they want me to download APKs and other files from places like Mediafire and Mega. I don't want to install files from places like that on my work phone!

I am looking for a comprehensive **written** description for how to upgrade my existing installations. It would also be very helpful if it included a background and overview of the process. E.g., describing what the difference is between VMOS and VMOS Pro, which of these you find on Google Play, the source for the APKs that you download from shady places like Mega and Mediafire, the principles behind the whole process etc, e.g., why isn't 12 included in the version on Google Play?

Comment: A common reason for apps not publishing updates on Google Play Store is that over the years Google has increased the restrictions (like latest targetSDK has to be used which means other restrictions). Under these restrictions some apps have just become impossible so they are not updated anymore in Play Store (well-known example: Termux).